# how to group clusters based on restaurants,hospitals,etc in Android?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-maps-utils

I am a newbie to Android programming. I have started with integrating `Google Maps` into my application. I have also used `clustering` of the map markers. I have used `maps-utils` library for the clustering. I am using the `grid` based algorithm for the clustering. My problem is as follows.

I am plotting markers for `hospitals` and `restaurants` currently. 
I want to group markers of hospitals into a cluster and restaurants into another clusters and make sure that both the clusters don't form into one cluster. Is there any way to do this.

Kindly help me step by step. I am following the demo available with the maps-utils library.

Comment: If   `demo available with the maps-utils library` then Why you ask question here?

Comment: Please take look [http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

You can try out [LeafLet marker cluster library](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster), it clusters the the markers having distinctive properties.